# sql find same two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
a b c
1 2 3
1 2 2
1 3 3
2 3 4
2 3 5
```

i want to find all same a+b's

for that data  my result should be

```
1 2 3 (look a and b)
1 2 2 (look a and b) they are same so should be in the result
**
2 3 4 (look a and b)
2 3 5 (look a and b) they are same so should be in the result
```

*

```
select count(a),a,count(b),b from Table A
group by a,b
having count(a)>1
and count(b)>1
```

That works like that I can see which ones are like that.
But I want to see RAW data.

How can I see all data with that having clause ?
Because that table have lots of columns and I dont want to group by them.
I only want group by a and b and see all the columns .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by a, b) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where cnt > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want can do what you want with `exists`:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where exists (
    select 1 
    from mytable t1 
    where t1.a = t.a and t1.b = t.b and t1.c <> t.c
)
```

Assuming that `(a, b, c)` tuples are unique, you can also do a window count:

```
select *
from (select t.*, count(*) over(partition by a, b) cnt from mytable t) t
where cnt = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a query that finds pairs of a's and b's that occur more than once, and then join it on the original table:

```sql
SELECT x.*
FROM   mytable x
JOIN   (SELECT a, b
        FROM   mytable
        GROUP BY a, b
        HAVING   COUNT(*) > 1) x ON x.a = y.a and x.b = y.b
```

Answer (score 0):

join the result with the original table like:

```sql
select * from
(
    select a,b
    from mytable 
    group by a,b
) X
left join  mytable Y on X.a = Y.a and X.b = Y.b;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to select that values which has duplicate one.

In the below query the duplicate values based on the column value `a` and `b` are considered as a table and joined with the original table.

```
create table RawDataTable (a int, b int, c int)
insert into RawDataTable values
(1,2,3), (1,2,2), (1,3,3), (2,3,4), (2,3,5)

SELECT a.*
FROM RawDataTable a
JOIN (
    SELECT a
        ,b
        ,COUNT(*) AS RN
    FROM RawDataTable
    GROUP BY a
        ,b
    HAVING count(*) > 1
    ) b ON a.a = b.a
    AND a.b = b.b
```

Here is the live [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bb34c5a68dc5b7abd2073f5ff873fb68) demo.